# If Value in Column B exists in Column A, return true, else, return false

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding comparing lists in Excel.

Basically, I want to see if the value in column B exists in the column A for all values in column B. If the does exist, I want to Return "Yes" beside that value in column C. I have tried:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2, A2:A5000),"Yes",),"No")
```

But this returns "Yes" for all values, even though I know for sure that this is not the case.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: This portion `MATCH(B2, A2:A5000)` shall be `MATCH(B2, A2:A5000,0)` if you are looking for exact MATCH.

Comment: Edit your question's title please. This will help others to find your questions easily.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2, A2:A5000,0),"Yes",),"No")
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried that but it still didn't work just right... realized what the correct code is: =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2, A$2:A$5000,0),"Yes",),"No")

Comment: Range array was not limited in Match()... so instead of A$2 i had A2... so when copying the function down the column it increased and therefore excluded some values

Comment: @MarkoDakic  Very nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

For a VBA solution that highlights duplicates and optionally spits out a list, see my answer at [Good way to compare and highlight thousands of rows in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390750/good-way-to-compare-and-highlight-thousands-of-rows-in-vba/48392007#48392007)